# How to pull from the remote using dulwich?

Tags: python, git, dulwich

How to do something like `git pull` in python dulwich library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used dulwich, but from [these doc's](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/tutorial/remote.html#fetching-objects-into-a-local-repository), possibly something like:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
from dulwich.client import HttpGitClient
local = Repo.init("local", mkdir=True)
client = HttpGitClient('http://github.com/adammorris/')
remote_refs = client.fetch("history.js.git",local)
local["HEAD"] = remote_refs["refs/heads/master"]
```

At this point, it didn't load the files, but I could do "git checkout" from the local path, and it updated the files.

Also, saw these:

- https://lists.launchpad.net/dulwich-users/msg00118.html
- [Programmatically `git checkout .` with dulwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640546/programmatically-git-checkout-with-dulwich)

Comment: Yes, the fetch function will pull in a pack file under `.git` directory. And I just don't know how to merge it into master branch.

Comment: It sounds like fetch() should import the pack into same branch as the repo.  Is possible to use do_commit() to merge it into the master branch?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904734/in-dulwich-how-do-i-commit-to-a-branch-instead-of-to-head

Comment: Tried this and found I needed to set the refs first, like local["HEAD"] = remote_refs["refs/heads/master"]  - saw this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640546/programmatically-git-checkout-with-dulwich

Answer (score 3):

Full example. Works with `Bitbucket`.

```py
from dulwich import index
from dulwich.client import HttpGitClient
from dulwich.repo import Repo

local_repo = Repo.init(LOCAL_FOLDER, mkdir=True)
remote_repo = HttpGitClient(REMOTE_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
remote_refs = remote_repo.fetch(REMOTE_URL, local_repo)
local_repo[b"HEAD"] = remote_refs[b"refs/heads/master"]

index_file = local_repo.index_path()
tree = local_repo[b"HEAD"].tree
index.build_index_from_tree(local_repo.path, index_file, local_repo.object_store, tree)
```

Replace LOCAL_FOLDER, REMOTE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD with your data.

Comment: if remote-repo uninitialized,  remote_refs[b"refs/heads/master"] raise  KeyError: b'refs/heads/master'