# Ironpython module has no attribute fsync

Tags: ironpython

I'm loading [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/) into ironpython and when I try to run the example code below from [How to pull from the remote using dulwich?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965471/how-to-pull-from-the-remote-using-dulwich)

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
from dulwich.client import HttpGitClient
local = Repo.init("local", mkdir=True)
client = HttpGitClient('http://github.com/adammorris/')
remote_refs = client.fetch("history.js.git",local)
local["HEAD"] = remote_refs["refs/heads/master"]
```

I get: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fsync'`.

I know that in the case of `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'` passing `-X:Frames` enables the appropriate call which is disabled by default for performance reasons. Is this a similar case and if not how should I proceed?

EDIT:
[image: screencap of traceback]

Comment: Can you find out which module is supposed to have fsync? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm running it on windows 7, and I'll add the traceback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [IronPython issue #7267](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/7267). I'll see if I can get a fix into 2.7.4.

Comment: Thank you! Will you be issuing a patch?

Comment: 2.7.4 should be out in about a month, with a bunch of other fixes as well.