# Dulwich ~ push to a certain branch

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I would like to do the following with [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich) in an existing git repo:

- change a file
- commit
- push to a certain branch (not master)

I read the documentation and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904734/in-dulwich-how-do-i-commit-to-a-branch-instead-of-to-head) on SO, but I don't get it. Can someone explain how to chose a specific branch to push to?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the push phase, you can specify how you would like to update the refs in the remote repository.

E.g. (untested)::

```
 from dulwich.client import get_transport_and_path
 from dulwich.repo import Repo
 repo = Repo(".")
 client, path = get_transport_and_path("git+ssh://git@github.com/jelmer/foo")
 def update_refs(refs):
     refs["refs/heads/somebranch"] = repo["refs/heads/somebranch"].id
 client.send_pack(path, update_refs, repo.object_store.generate_pack_data)
```